# error: cannot find symbol import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory

Tags: java, android-studio, exoplayer, android-video-player, m3u

There is an error when building project

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
^
symbol:   class DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory
location: package com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream
```

Can not import the DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory class. but all dependencies are added. What is this problem's solution?

Here is my Gradle dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.testiptv'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testiptv"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.18.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.4'
  //  implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.8'


    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.18.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.18.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.18.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.4'
}
```

Here is my Manifest file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestIPTV"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".videoplayer"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is exoplayer xml design

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".videoplayer"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    app:show_subtitle_button="false"
    app:hide_on_touch="true"
    app:use_controller="true"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_exo_view"
    app:show_vr_button="false"
    app:resize_mode="fill"
    app:show_shuffle_button="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my Java code that inserts a M3U link that is trying to play Exoplayer.

```java
package com.example.testiptv;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;

public class videoplayer extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected PlayerView playerView;

    SimpleExoPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoplayer);

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        playvideo();
    }

    private void playvideo() {
        //String videouri = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
        String videouri = "https://stmv.video.expressolider.com.br/ghostv/ghostv/playlist.m3u8";

        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videouri);
            player = new SimpleExoPlayer(videoplayer.this);

            playerView.setPlayer(player);

            // Create an HTTPS data source factory
            DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                    "exoplayer-codelab",
                    DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                    DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                    true /* allowCrossProtocolRedirects */,
                    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory.DEFAULT_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY);

            // Create a media source using the data source factory
            MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
            Log.d(TAG, "Media source created: " + (mediaSource != null));

            // Set the media source for the player
            player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);

            // Prepare the player
            player.prepare();

            // Start playing the video
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing player", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        player.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [Exoplayer release notes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md), `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory` is removed in version 2.16.0 and you should use `DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory` instead.